# Proper way to start Java Swing desktop application

Tags: java, multithreading, model-view-controller, swing, user-interface

What is the proper way to start the application that needs 5-10 seconds to retrieve initial data from the database? This is what I got so far but I am not sure that there are no better ways. I would like that GUI and database access would be in different threads so that GUI building would occur concurrently with data retrieval.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Controller controller = new Controller();
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            View frame = new View();
            controller.setView(frame);
        }
    });
    Model model = new Model();
    controller.setModel(model);
    controller.getInitialData();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the problem is. You need to design your GUI so that it can react to changes in the model when the database access is done. In the same way a `JTable` listens for events from a `TableModel`, your overall UI should listen for events (like "DB access done") from the model.

Comment: You can display a [splash screen](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/splashscreen/) while the data is loading, before the GUI comes up.  Otherwise you could also start the GUI, freeze it and display some message while the data is loading.

Comment: Yes, definitely do your database work in a separate thread. I would imagine that your getInitialData method body would create a SwingWorker and get the data itself from inside of the SwingWorker and then as mentioned in the comments above, notify the GUI when this action was complete.

Comment: all of these are excellent suggestions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're sort-of on the right track. Hopefully this will make things a little more clear...

Swing is not thread-safe. That being said, there are a couple things you can do. One option is to use [`SwingUtilities`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html) to post a `Runnable` task on the Event Dispatch Thread to be executed. This will enable you to retrieve data from the database and update the UI in a separate thread while respecting Swing's single-threaded model.

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        //  update UI
    } 
});
```

Another option, since this is a long-running task, is to use [`SwingWorker`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) to provide updates to the UI either when done, or while processing.

As you can see, both of these mechanisms (i.e. `SwingUtilities` and `SwingWorker`) enable you to dedicate such tasks to other threads while providing you with the ability to place the result (which normally translates into an action) on the `EventQueue` for later (and safe) execution. Regardless of which one you choose, it is important to remember that long-running tasks should never take place in the `EDT`. And thus, as I've come to discover, the most important feature of any well-designed GUI is *responsiveness*.