# How to initialize gui objects in a thread safe manner in java swing?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, thread-safety, event-dispatch-thread

I'm reading Thinking in Java and the author stresses that main method shouldn't call swing methods. As an example of that practice he presents the following piece of code (available on his webpage):

```
//: gui/SubmitSwingProgram.java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class SubmitSwingProgram extends JFrame {
  JLabel label;
  public SubmitSwingProgram() {
    super("Hello Swing");
    label = new JLabel("A Label");
    add(label);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(300, 100);
    setVisible(true);
  }
  static SubmitSwingProgram ssp;
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() { ssp = new SubmitSwingProgram(); }
    });
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        ssp.label.setText("Hey! This is Different!");
      }
    });
  }
} ///:~
```

The gui object is then created and initialized through invokeLater method making it thread safe. But few pages later the author presents the following code:

```
//: gui/Button2.java
// Responding to button presses.
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import static net.mindview.util.SwingConsole.*;

public class Button2 extends JFrame {
  private JButton
    b1 = new JButton("Button 1"),
    b2 = new JButton("Button 2");
  private JTextField txt = new JTextField(10);
  class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      String name = ((JButton)e.getSource()).getText();
      txt.setText(name);
    }
  }
  private ButtonListener bl = new ButtonListener();
  public Button2() {
    b1.addActionListener(bl);
    b2.addActionListener(bl);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    add(b1);
    add(b2);
    add(txt);
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    run(new Button2(), 200, 150);
  }
} ///:~
```

where SwingConsole is:

```
//: net/mindview/util/SwingConsole.java
// Tool for running Swing demos from the
// console, both applets and JFrames.
package net.mindview.util;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SwingConsole {
  public static void
  run(final JFrame f, final int width, final int height) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        f.setTitle(f.getClass().getSimpleName());
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(width, height);
        f.setVisible(true);
      }
    });
  }
} ///:~
```

So contrary to the previous example an object implementing JFrame is created and initialized within the main method / main thread.

My question is then:
(1) Is the second example wrong or is the first one exaggerated?
(2) Is it enough that I call swing methods through invokeLater only after the setVisible call and before that statement it is safe to call swing methods within main thread?

Comment: It could he argued that until the frame is packed or made visible (aka as realised), it safe to deal with. The problem with this thinking is, you just don't know what is going to trigger a request the event queue. It is always safer to initialise  the UI from within the context of the EDT

Comment: This may be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393327/proper-way-to-start-java-swing-desktop-application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second example is wrong. Swing components must be created and used from the event dispatch thread. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html.

Quote from [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html):

> Calls to an application's main method, or methods in Applet, are not invoked on the event dispatching thread. As such, care must be taken to transfer control to the event dispatching thread when **constructing and showing** an application or applet.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Yup.  Even though `run()` is a call to a method which invokes the proper SwingUtilities method, the actual construction (the call to `new`) is invoked on the main thread.  Not good!

Comment: Thank you for a great answer, the links explain everything. I am surprised though, I thought Thinking in Java is considered to be one of the better sources for learning the language.

Answer (score -1):

<del>The example with the main() method might be a bit misleading. The rule AFAIK is that only the main thread is allowed to execute Swing updates/redraws etc. and the main() method per definitionem **is** the main thread. All other threads are required to schedule stuff via SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...). It might be that even for the main thread it improves latencies since you might do time consuming stuff in the main thread and schedule GUI refreshes foe whenever the main thread is less busy.</del>
EDIT: Proven Wrong

Comment: I think your confusing terms, generally the main thread is considered the thread which starts your program (calls main), where as Swing uses a different thread, known as the event dispatching thread, where all UI code should be executed from