# How to make a Timer that waits one second & then continues on with program?

Tags: java, swing, timer, jframe, jpanel

How could I create a timer that is compatible in a `JFrane`/`JPanel` oriented program where it just waits 1 second, and then continues on with the rest of the code?

I do not want to use `Thread.sleep();` since it is causing problems for me.

Comment: Do you actually want to delay the GUI-Thread (meaning your GUI will freeze for the delay) or just one single event? For the latter (which is probably what you want), @Puce's answer seems to do the job.

Answer (score 4):

For this kind of tasks you can use [javax.swing.Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html). It integrates with the Event Dispatching Thread (EDT).

Answer (score -1):

```
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1)
```

More helpful information here:
[How to delay in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104313/how-to-delay-in-java)

Comment: That linked question is about an app. with no GUI. Apps. with GUIs require special consideration (see the answer of @Puce for how to do it).  The OP even *mentions* having problems using `sleep()` ..

Comment: I'm fairly certain it doesn't matter if there is a GUI or not. Plenty of examples of GUIs using TimeUnit to delay their app. One google search returned plenty of examples. And I didn't realize TimeUnit.sleep() was just overhead for Thread.sleep(). My mistake.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26834078/how-to-initialize-gui-objects-in-a-thread-safe-manner-in-java-swing

Comment: @jknam all three of your examples already use multithreading. This is a huge difference. I think Andrew Thompson spoke of examples, in which the GUI-Thread is being paused (which causes the GUI to be unresponsive).